# How is this proof that $a+0=a$ correct?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, real-numbers

I found this in the 4th edition of Spivak's *Calculus* (which I have just begun reading) on page 4:

If $a+x=a$ then $(-a)+(a+x)=(-a)+a=0$.

Hence $((-a) + a) + x = 0$
[from $(a + b) + c = a + (b + c)$ and $(-a) + a = 0$, both of them had been previously mentioned]

Hnce $0 + x = 0$. Finally $x = 0$.

My problem is on the last line; we're proving that $a + 0 = a$, but aren't we using the fact that $0 + a = 0$, to conclude from $0 + x = 0$ that $x = 0$?

Comment: The author is proving that: if $a+x=a$, then $x=0$.

Comment: In doing so, he uses the fact that $0+x=x$ (and yes, he relies also on previously proved facts, like associativity, commutativity: $a+b=b+a$ and def of inverse: $(-a)+a=0$).

Comment: Mauro is right. We know from the additive identity property that $a+0=a$. What we're proving is that $0$ is the *only* number with this property.

Comment: You said "we're proving that $a+0=a$". No, that's not what we're doing here. We already know that $a+0=a$, that's an accepted fact (proven or axiomatic), and it suggests that $x=0$ is indeed a possible solution. What is being proven in that derivation is that $x=0$ is the *only* possible solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're working in a field, as I think Spivak deals with them first.

The field axioms are the defining properties of a field and its operations. One of the axioms states that in a field $\mathbb{F}$, there exists some element in the field (which we call $0$, the "additive identity") such that for every element $a\in\mathbb{F}$,

$$a+0=0+a=a.$$

Axioms are something that you simply state as true without proof. All fields must satisfy the axioms - if it doesn't then it's not a field (and we don't really care about it). In this case, we *define* $0$ to be the additive identity, and because we are working in a field we know it must exist (the axioms say so).

In the proof you are referring to, we are not proving that $a+0=a$. It would be pointless to prove this, as it is true by definition. What we are proving is that $0$ is unique. That is, the *only* element in $\mathbb{F}$ that is an additive identity is the $0$ that's defined in the axiom. To do this, we first suppose that $x\in\mathbb{F}$ satisfies $a+x=a$ for all $a\in\mathbb{F}$. With a little bit of work (and using the other field axioms), we show that this implies $x=0$. Basically,

$$a+x=a\implies x=0.$$

This means that $0$ is the only element that is an additive identity, and we are done.